# Angular: How to set values for select dropdown separetely using formcontrol

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have a list of food categories. Then I have a table for a list of food items and there is a field for foodcategory which classifies which category this item falls. The food category is being mapped based on Guid but is being displayed in readable format for the user. For every dropdown a new form instance is being used. How can I set the value separately. Using the exisiting code, all of them will have the same as it using same form control name.

Here is my code snippet.

```
    <tr *ngFor="let food of foodItems" id="{{food.Guid}}" class="alternate-row">
      <td><label>{{food.foodName}}</label></td>
      <td><label>{{food.foodDescription}}</label></td>
      <td>
        <form class="table_form" [formGroup]="tableForm" (ngSubmit)="onTableFormSubmit(tableForm.value)">
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="foodCategorySelect" (change)="onTableFormSubmit(tableForm.value, food.Guid)">
            <option *ngFor="let foodCategory of foodCategoryList" [value]="foodCategory.Guid" [selected]="foodCategory.Guid == food.category">
              {{ foodCategory.categoryName }}
            </option>
          </select>    
        </form> 
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my logged value data:

```
    foodCategoryList
    0: 
    Guid: "b6b64fba-1879-44fb-8a8d-1b26c2229367"
    categoryName: "Starter"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    1: 
    Guid: "ba9e3828-ddf0-4db4-bff2-2ec668d973d0"
    categoryName: "Dessert"
    [[Prototype]]: Object

    foodList
    0: 
    foodName: "Chicken Wings"
    Guid: "ec34ce1f-5274-4d32-a17f-4a518fef9a1f"
    foodDescription: "Delicious spicy chicken wings served with sauce"
    category: "b6b64fba-1879-44fb-8a8d-1b26c2229367" --starter
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Please help.. Cant seem to find a way

Comment: what is tableForm in your case? would you like the whole table to be the same form? or rather every row would be a small form?

Comment: @Andrei, every row is a form which pertains to each corresponding record in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you want each row to be a form i would propose to use templates forms (for simplicity)

```
<!-- no <form> element needed -->
<select [(ngModel)]="food.category"  <!-- binding of category -->
(ngModelchange)="onTableFormSubmit(food.category, food.Guid)"> <!-- update call when it changes -->
...
```

and that should already work.

If you still want to use reactive forms api, then you'd be required to create an instance of reactive piece for every row, and then either put the form in the model

```
foodItemsTableData = this.foodItems.map(food => ({
  ...food,
  categoryControl: 
}))
```

which is a bit ugly. but binding would be just `[formControl]="food.categoryControl"`

or make an indexes dependance

```
// ts
foodCategoriesControls = this.foodItems.map(food => new FormControl(food.category));
// subscriptions to updates could be in typescript file in this case if you want to
...
// html
<tr *ngFor="let food of foodItems; index as i"
<select [formControl]="foodCategoriesControls[i]" (change)="onTableFormSubmit(foodCategoriesControls[i].value, food.value)"
```

you could also wrap the categories controlls inside of forms as you were doing in your example, but it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I tried template forms but now getting this error in console  ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.

Comment: remove the form wrapper